# Use the return value of a service method to construct another service?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

With Symfony 3 Dependency Injection component, how can I use the return value of a method on one service as an argument for the constructor on another service?

For example, I'm looking for the configuration syntax to mimic this:

```
<?php

class Foo {
  public function getParam() {
    // ...
    return $param;
  }
}

class Bar {
  public function __construct ($param) {
    // ...
  }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$bar = new Bar($foo->getParam());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [Use a Factory to Create Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html) or [Inject Values Based on Complex Expressions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html) (via expression language starting from sf 2.4) as example, in yaml format:

<kbd>services.yml</kbd>

```
services:
    app.foo:
        class:        Foo

    app.bar:
        class:        Bar
        arguments:    ["@=service('foo').getParam()"]
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

You should not do this, because you should [not construct components using runtime data](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99). Instead, you should simply inject `Foo` into `Bar`. This way, `Bar` can call `getParam()` *at runtime*, i.e. after the object graph has been constructed:

```
class Bar {
  private $foo;
  public function __constract ($foo) {
    $this->foo = $foo;
  }

  public function handle() {
    $this->foo.getParam();
  }
}

// Composition Root
$bar = new Bar(new Foo());
```

Comment: Hi @Steven I agree with  you about your suggestion, the framework that the user ask for permit this kind of operation. I utilise this features with parsimony

Comment: @Steven - The link you posted seems to focus on request specific data aka runtime.  It's not clear how applicable it is to this question.  Yes there are times when you need to use the service locator pattern but dependency injection is usually better.  Of course when you are dealing with someone naming their services foo and bar then context goes out the window.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of context.  In my specific case, `Foo` provides access to configuration information.  So `getParam()` might return a configured date format string for the application.  I did not want `Bar` to be tied to `Foo` when it's only needs the date format string.

Comment: @user2045006 In case it is configuration information, you should typically load that information once (since it is typically static for the application) before you configure your dependencies. This means calling `foo.getParam()` once at 'startup'. After that you can supply that configuration value as constructor argument to `Bar`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found shortly after posting this was to store the the result of Foo::getParam() as another service.

```
<container>
    <services>
        <service id="foo" class="Foo" />

        <service id="foo.param" public="false">
            <factory service="foo" method="getParam" />
        </service>

        <service id="bar" class="Bar">
            <argument type="service" id="foo.param" />
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

I don't believe this is as nice the accepted solution.